# Error: Failed retrieving GitHub repository, When i try to deploy nuxt to netlify

Tags: vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, netlify

Trying to deploy my nuxt.js app to Netlify using Netlify CLI but I keep getting this error

```
Adding deploy key to repository...
 »   Error: Failed retrieving GitHub repository information with error: Not Found. Does the repository netlify_app exist and accessible by myusername
```

i used this command `netlify init`

i have granted access to my GitHub and it is in my GitHub repo but private.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, i just found the issue.
My Repo was private and i was using a starter account
Read more..
https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/troubleshooting-tips/?_gl=1%2ayvop78%2a_gcl_au%2aODc3NDM0NDUyLjE2ODc1NTY5MDQ.&_ga=2.257195595.1550143071.1688559156-1964596046.1687556914#organization-owned-private-repository